# Odd SVN reverse merge error messages

Tags: svn, merge, restore, revert

Trying to reverse merge to recover 1 specific file.  I believe I understand how it's supposed to work, but getting odd errors.

I've reread the svn book, Google and stack, etc.

The problem:

I want to specify 1 specific file to restore.

SVN doesn't like the local file reference because the file doesn't exist, but online examples seem to use the local file name.

It also doesn't like the full http path, because it doesn't exist in the repository.  I know it doesn't exist now, but it was there. Even using @peg syntax still gives an error.

Example:

- In revision **100** I remove a bunch of files, so **r99** was the last point in time it existed.
- We're now at revision **150** and I want just one file back.
- Let's say the file is called **.myFile** (with a leading dot, don't think that matters)
- Project URL and "working directory" is http://server/repo/Project/trunk
- The file's URL would have been http://server/repo/Project/trunk/.myFile
- Assume I'm in the equivalent filesystem directory, with no pending updates or commits, in other words **svn status --show-updates .** shows I'm up to date.
- And I'm able to do svn cat http://server/repo/Project/trunk/.myFile@99

Failed Attempts:

```
svn merge -c -100 .myFile
Error: .myFile not under version control

svn merge -c -100 http://server/repo/Project/trunk/.myFile
Error: svn: '/repo/!svn/bc/120/Project/.myFile' path not found
Note that rev 120 is between the delete (r100) and now (r150)

svn merge -c -100 http://server/repo/Project/trunk/.myFile@99
Error: svn: File not found: revision 100, path '/Project/trunk/.myFile'

svn merge -c -100 . .myFile
Don't recall specific error.

svn merge -c -100 . http://server/repo/Project/trunk/.myFile@99
Error: svn: Cannot specify a revision range with two URLs
```

... and various other combinations....

I'm really stumped.  I believe I understand about the reverse merge, and about why @pegs are sometimes needed, but this particular combination is quite vexing.

I have workarounds: I could restore all the files then cleanup.  Or just copy and paste an older version in, I could do that with the svn cat command.

But I'd like to understand the "correct" way.

Answer (score 1):

Working on a slightly different issue today, I believe I've finally found my answer.

I was merging changes from an individual file, vs. restoring a deleted copy, so not quite the same thing.

One key change I made:

- I used an explicit -r FROM : TO range, instead of just using the -c shortcut.

Other points:

- source should be in the URL form
- destination should be in the local ./filename form

Hypothetical example revision recap:

- Currently the system is as r150
- Files were removed in r100
- Files were last present in r99 (though not modified)
- Files were last added/updated in r85
- Note: my example filename is a Unix hidden file so it starts with a dot - most files wouldn't have that.

Undo deletion, I think it would be:

```
cd localWorkDir/Project/trunk
svn update
svn merge -r100:85 http://server/repo/Project/trunk/.myFile ./.myFile
svn commit -m "restoring files"
(message saying committed r151)
```

So I think the -c syntax, when merging individual files, is problematic.